# Parse a partial json-esque string in a text file to a python list

Tags: python, json, list

I have a textfile with the below content (its much bigger, but shortened for readability).

```
[
{"entities": [{"name": "charges", "type": "OTHER"}, {"name": "maha", "type": "OTHER"} ], "language": "en"}, 
{"entities": [{"name": "call", "type": "OTHER"}, {"name": "bounce charges", "type": "OTHER" }], "language": "en"}
]
```

How do I parse it to a python list. I have gone through a couple of stackoverflow questions, but none of them seems to talk about this format of data.

Once I can get the above done, I can then use the below logic to generate a csv file.

```
reslis = []

for dic in master_list:
    seclis = dic['entities']
    for diic in seclis:
        temp_dict = {}
        temp_dict['name'] = diic['name']
        temp_dict['type'] = diic['type']
        reslis.append(temp_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(reslis)
df.to_csv("reslis.csv")
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Try the `json` module. Look for the `load`, `loads` methods.

Comment: `with open(my_file) as f: data = json.loads(f.read())`